# Php lumen, artisan passport:install error

Tags: php, lumen

Following all the instructions in the document of dusterio / lumen-passport,

Running php artisan passport:install after all the instructions in the document gives me the following error.

```
Encryption keys generated successfully.
Personal access client created successfully.
Client ID: 1
Client secret: EQXIlANzcONLH7IvXOi6bRuSHxOqemZVKjMOHC5I

In ChoiceQuestion.php line 36:

Choice question must have at least 1 choice available.
```

Been on this the entire night.

Comment: Share the relevant lines from `ChoiceQuestion`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I guess you have followed this [documentation](https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport).

This type of error comes when `$app->configure('auth');` could not find the `auth.php` at `<YOUR_PROJECT>/config/auth.php`.

While make mistake to put the `config` directory in `app` viz. `<YOUR_PROJECT>/app/config/auth.php`

Check the config directory location, it must be just under the project's root  directory.

Comment: it works like a charm now, the structure of the directory must be the nex one 
`<project>/
app
boostrap
config
....

`

Answer (score -1):

**STEP 1:** Add `$app->configure('auth');` in your `bootstrap\app.php`

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Dusterio\LumenPassport\PassportServiceProvider::class);
$app->configure('auth');
```

**STEP 2:** Go to file `vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\config\auth.php` and change the `'guards'` and `'providers'`

```
'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users'
        ],
    ],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => \App\Models\User::class
    ]
],
```

**STEP 3:** Run `php artisan migrate:fresh`

**STEP 4:** Run `php artisan passport:install --force`

Comment: Why should we change the files in vendor directory ?